# When trying to link an image in a figure, nothing happens?

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a figure that I would like to link to an email, but when I add the  tag, nothing happens. How do I fix this?

```html
<figure>
  <a href="mailto:#">
    <img src="images/slides/slide2.2.png" alt="class-header-3d" width="900" height="450" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-174" />
  </a>
  <figcaption><strong>Game Submission now open! Click the image for direct link to e-mail.</strong>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Do you have outlook?

Comment: You need to have a email client to achieve what you want...On this side everything works fine

Comment: Try using a different link for the image, it isn't just email, nothing is linking.

Comment: I have figured out this error is being caused because of the CSS, how do I fix it from there? I will add the relevant CSS code in an answer below.

Comment: On my PC, if I click on your `a` link, my email client opens up with the email address inserted in the "mail to` field.  I am using Win7 and Thunderbird.  There is something else going on that is outside of the code itself.

Comment: @MarcAudet, please refer to answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.css-slideshow {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 900px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 2em auto .5em auto;
}
.css-slideshow figure {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 900px;
  height: 450px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
}
.css-slideshow img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
}
.css-slideshow figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  font-family: "Calibri";
}
.css-slideshow:hover figure figcaption {
  transition: opacity .5s;
  opacity: 1;
}
.css-slideshow-attr {
  max-width: 900px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: .7em;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.css-slideshow-attr a {
  color: #666;
}
.css-slideshow figure {
  opacity: 0;
}
figure:nth-child(1) {
  animation: xfade 48s 42s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(2) {
  animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(3) {
  animation: xfade 48s 30s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(4) {
  animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(5) {
  animation: xfade 48s 18s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(6) {
  animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(7) {
  animation: xfade 48s 6s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(8) {
  animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes xfade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  10.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

It should also be noted that the figure is wrapped by a div (div class="css-slideshow")

Comment: This is not really an answer, you should update your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on our end. You need an email client like Outlook or Thunderbird for the `mailto` action to perform. Even if your gmail is open you can test through that too.